# HTTP Bad Request error because of a character

Tags: php, apache, http

I am using .htaccess to convert a link with the following parameters...:

*www.domain.com*/ `offer.php?id=`**1000**`&title=`**All shirts are with a discount of 20%**

to

*www.domain.com*/ `offer/`**1000**`/`**All shirts are with a discount of 20%**

Now when I try opening the link I get displayed a server side error:

> Bad Request 
>   Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

In my code the `title` value does not play any role, but I need it for SEO reasons. So when I remove the "**%**" character from the link the page opens without a problem.

So how can I fix this issue so my link will open despite the percentage character in the HTTP request?

Comment: It might be nice if we could see the `.htaccess rewrite rule`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by [Nordenheim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40509706/3536236) the problem is using special characters in your title attribute.

Using PHP you may well want to use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on your `title` attribute on the sending link,

So:

```
<?php

$title = "All shirts are with a discount of 20%";
$link = urlencode($title);

?>
<a href='http://www.domain.com/offer.php?id=1000&title=<?php print $link;?>'>Click here</a>
```

This will turn `All shirts are with a discount of 20%` into the URL safe string `All+shirts+are+with+a+discount+of+20%25` and will resolve the error you are getting from your `.htaccess` mod_rewrite.

Comment: Anywhere I can see a list of the forbidden characters? Since a lot of them actually work just fine with the HTTP request?

Comment: @FrankHelligberger Yes, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/3536236)

Answer (score 2):

The percent sign (`%`) is used to encode special characters in a url string. Hence, it  has special meaning, and must be passed as an encoded character, which is `%25`.

Since you pass an indication of a special character and do not send anything else, you get the error.